# Problems with password_hash() and password_verify()

Tags: php, mysql

Well I'm making a login system with MySQL and PHP. Then I want to crypt the user's password using password_hash and password_verify functions. But it isn't work for me at the time of compare the dehashed password with the hashed password (password_verify func).

So here is my code.

**signup.php**

```
$password_hashed = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost"=>15));

$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)");


if ($statement && empty($result1)) {
   $result = $statement->execute( [
    ':username' => $data['username'],
    ':email' => $data['email'],
    ':password' => $password_hashed,
]);

header('Location: register.php');
$_SESSION['messages'][] = 'Thank you for registration. Check your email then log in.';
exit();
}
```

**login.php**

```
if ($user['username'] === $username && $user['password'] === password_verify($user['password'], $password)) {
    header("Location: panel.php");
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
    die();
} else {
    $_SESSION['messages'][] = 'Incorrect user or password!';
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

**Where $password:** `$password = $data['password'];`

**Where $user:**

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
$statement->execute([':username' => $username]);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user = array_shift($result);
```

**Output:** `Incorrect user or password!`

Comment: `password_verify()` returns `true`, not the hash, so `$user['password'] == $boolValue` doesn't make sense

Comment: Is this academic code to learn about PHP or for a production site?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "dehashed" password. The whole point of `password_hash` is to make it as difficult as possible to ever brute-force guess it. They're intended to be [one way only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a boolean (true/false) value:

```
password_verify($user['password'], $password)
```

So this will ***never*** be `true`:

```
$user['password'] === password_verify($user['password'], $password)
```

Once you've selected the user from the database based on the provided username, just verify the password:

```
if (password_verify($user['password'], $password)) {
```

---

A couple notes on your terminology, becase it's important...

> I want to crypt the user's password

No, you do not want to *en*crypt the user's password.  You want to "hash" it.  It's an important distinction.  Encrypted things can be returned to their original form.  Hashed things can not.  Which is a vital part of password security.

> compare the dehashed password with the hashed password

There's no "dehashed" anything.  What the internals of `password_verify` does is hash the provided password and compare that result with the already-hashed stored password.  At no point can you in any way convert the stored hashed password back to its original form.